# What is the motivation behind ADA2200-style half-wave synchronous demodulator?

Tags: analog, demodulation, switched-capacitor

I came across an interesting IC that contains most components of a little lock-in amplifier (except output LPF) - [ADA2200](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ada2200.pdf). I am curious however why they opted for such a design where instead of flipping signal input polarity every half-cycle of the reference, they just hold the input constant for a half-cycle of the reference (RCLK on the diagram below). This, I think, won't provide any better harmonic rejection, but I may be mistaken.
Maybe it's just because flipping polarity is awkward in the configuration they got?
[image]
[image]